# Sort Button in Access Form

Tags: sorting, ms-access, vba

So I have a form that has a subform that displays projects. The goal is to create a sort button that would allow me to to sort/filter the project list by name and then priority. So my question is if there was a way to have two or more sort/filter criteria in a sort/filter button? I know I'm able to sort on one field using the .SetFocus and then DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSortAscending but is that applicable to multiple fields? ie: Sort by Name AND Priority (High, Medium, Low). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `OrderBy` property of the form. You can set it to anything that would be valid as an ORDER BY in the SQL of the form recordset.

```
Me.OrderBy = "[Name], [Priority] DESC"
Me.Requery
```

Comment: So will the Me.OrderBy know to target the subform? or do I need to setfocus to the subform and then do the Me.OrderBy?

Comment: If you are not calling it from the subform's module you have to qualify it. For example if calling from the parent form: `Me.[SubFormName]!OrderBy="Filter"` Or from a global function: `Forms("MainFormName").[SubFormName]!OrderBy="Filter"`. Final syntax may be a little different as I am writing this on the fly.